# Jquery selecting all table data in my tables

Tags: jquery

I'm new to Jquery FYI. I'm trying to get all the table data in my table to display in my console but its not working. I selected all table rows iterate through each to find all table data and for that console log it but its not working. Some explanation would be helpful !

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#divTable td').each(function(){
        var tableData = $(this);
        console.log($(tableData).val());

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myContent">
  <p>My Jquery enabled page</p>
</div>
<br>
<div id="divTable">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <!--table heading-->
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What's `':tr'`?

Comment: You dont need to get around tableData with selector, you should use "console.log(tableData.val())" instead

Comment: and use text() function instead of val() because val() function used for getting data of input tags

Comment: thank you @hsnble . I was watching a video on plural sight and they didn't say when to use.val and .text but thanks for clarifying it. (y)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to iterate through `<tr>` elements, it should be done the same was as you did through the `<td>` elements - that is, without the `:`.

That being said, looping through the `<tr>` elements isn't really necessary, as the `<td>` elements will *always* be within `<tr>` tags. The outer `each()` can simply be removed.

Last thing I'd change: You're logging each `<td>` as a jQuery element, when I'd assume you want the text inside the cell, rather than the cell object itself. I've added a `.text()` in my example to demonstrate.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      var tableData = $(this).text();
      console.log(tableData);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myContent">
  <p>My Jquery enabled page</p>
</div>
<br>
<div id="divTable">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <!--table heading-->
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```